# Rails how to get customer name in orders view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to learn rails, building very simple app.

by going to

```
<%= link_to 'Show Orders', orders_path %>)
```

I get list of orders for one customer. There are some attributes stored for customer, including first name and second name.

I try to create header with text "Listing orders for John":

```
<h1>Listing Orders for <%= @customer.try(:name) %></h1>
```

Result is:

```
Listing Orders for
```

What do i do wrong?

UPD:

Well, customer and order actually "nicknames" for Feature and Assets (relations are the same), for easier understanding. Sorry for confusing.

So, Assets controller show method:

```
class AssetsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_asset, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def show
end

private
def set_asset
  @asset = Asset.find(params[:id])
end
```

Feature model:

```
class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :assets, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Asset model:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :feature
end
```

Comment: Check in the console if the `@customer` your trying to display `name` for doesn't have `nil` in his `name` column.

Comment: Please post your controller show action and order and user model

Comment: Added show action and order and user model.

All columns are not null. I can change name to id - id can't be null. Still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally managed it. A bit different approach - i now show assets on features pages.

```
class FeaturesController < ApplicationControll

def show
@assets = Asset.where(feature_id: @feature.id)
end
```

And in features/show.html.erb

```
<h2>Assets</h2>
<%= render @feature.assets %>
```

Seems like total magic to me, but still works just like needed.

This is closed now.

Answer (score 0):

**[try](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try) returns nil instead of raising exception**.So that customer.name is nil.I am sure it wont be coming for all customers.remove try and code will raise exception as name is nil

Comment: Well, there's only TWO customers. And all fields are filled in. Seems, i do smth wrong with Active Record.

Comment: @AlexeyDerevyanko  kindly debug in the controller to get an idea..and let me know for what you see. :)